# How to rotate embedded youtube video to landscape mode

Tags: ios, youtube, embed, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using the following embed code to embed my youtube videos on IOS

```
- (NSString*)embedYouTube:(NSString*)youtube_id frame:(CGRect)frame {  
   NSString* embedHTML = @"\
   <html><head>\
   <style type=\"text/css\">\
   body {\
   background-color: transparent;\
   color: white;\
   }\
   </style>\
   </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
   <iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></iframe>\
   </body></html>"; 
   NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, youtube_id, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

   return html;
}

//code to embed video
NSString *contentHTML;
if (currentAnswer.youtube_id != nil) {
    contentHTML = [self embedYouTube:currentAnswer.youtube_id frame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + CELL_AVATAR_WIDTH + CELL_SPACING, currentYAxisValue, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_WIDTH, CELL_YOUTUBEVIEW_HEIGHT)];
}

[webView loadHTMLString: contentHTML baseURL:nil];
```

When I play the video, it only plays in potrait mode and not landscape mode. Is this a restriction due to the 'iframes', is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

It should work provided that your UIViewController is also able to rotate to landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Test that your UIViewController is able to rotate before trying to rotate the video. If you don't want your UIViewController to be able to rotate when the video isn't on the screen, you could just do something like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(webView && webView.superView) return YES;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: This code does not exist in my main UIViewController, in fact, the web view to play youtube exists in a uitableviewcell. How do I handle the orientation of a uiwebview within a uitable?

Comment: You still have to put that code inside your UIViewController (the one that contains your UITable)

Answer (score 0):

In your UIViewController, set its view to webView:

> [self setView:webView];

Your webview is not receiving the rotation messages sent to the root view controller.  You can also use the `addChildViewController` method if you made a separate View Controller solely for your webView.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same as another question I just answered, [Fix Notification center orientation after the app resume execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314314/fix-notification-center-orientation-after-the-app-resume-execution/11374837)

YouTube videos have there own UIViewController subclass that presents them. They don't actually implement -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation; (that I know) and so use whatever orientation you are currently in.

If your app doesn't rotate to landscape then it won't be in landscape either. Setting the [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusbarOrientation should set the Youtube video's orientation, however if you choose to do this only, rather then implement [Michael Frederick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287026/458205) suggestion (as well), it could have some unusual effects when coming out of the video (like the UI portrait but stats bar landscape covering the UI).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

- (void) setTransformForCurrentOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    NSInteger degrees = 0;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) { degrees = -90; } 
        else { degrees = 90; }
    } else {
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) { degrees = 180; } 
        else { degrees = 0; }
    }

    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(degrees));

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [webView setTransform:rotationTransform];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```