# Fix Notification center orientation after the app resume execution

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have a view that is made to be displayed in landscape mode only, and is working well. But if you send the app to the background and then resume it, the notification center will appear in the orientation you had the device when resuming the app (usually portrait mode), so when I detect a swipe from left to right sometimes the notification center will appear. Any ideas how I can make the system know that it should show the notification center in landscape mode?

**EDIT**: The view displays in landscape mode as it should, the problem is only with the notification center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the status bar orientation sets the apps orientation. Alerts, NotificationCenter they all use the [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusbarOrientation as *the* orientation.

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation should do it all for you but if, as you are saying, it isn't then you can set the orientation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically stop a portrait mode coming into play in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, the following code is how you do that:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, the view is displayed correctly in landscape mode, but the notification center won't.

Comment: And actually, is easier doing that with just this line: `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`

Comment: Ahhh, my bad, it was in your first line.